# C# generic class inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a base class BaseRepository which other classes extend.

```
public class BaseRepository
{
    protected RestClient client;
    protected string url;

    public BaseRepository ()
    {
        client = RestClient.GetInstance ();
    }

    public async Task<T> Find<T> (string id) {
        dynamic response = await client.Find(url, id);

        return DeserializeItem<T> (response);
    }
}
```

and then I have a UsersRepository class which extends from the base class.

```
public class UsersRepository : BaseRepository
{
    string url = "users";
    static UsersRepository instance;

    private UsersRepository ()
    {
    }

    public static UsersRepository GetInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new UsersRepository ();
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to pass `User` as the response type for the `public async Task<T> Find<T> (string id)` method. I could create this method in the `UsersRepository` but I do not want to duplicate the code.

```
public override function User Find(string id) {
    return base.Find<User>(id);
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you actually want the generic type defined on the base class and not the method.  Also I think you want to set the `url` defined in the base class in the constructor of the derived class.

```
public class BaseRepository<T>
{
    protected RestClient client;
    protected string url;

    public BaseRepository ()
    {
        client = RestClient.GetInstance ();
    }

    public async Task<T> Find(string id) {
        dynamic response = await client.Find(url, id);

        return DeserializeItem<T> (response);
    }
}

public class UsersRepository : BaseRepository<User>
{
    static UsersRepository instance;

    private UsersRepository ()
    {
        url = "users";
    }

    public static UsersRepository GetInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new UsersRepository ();
        }

        return instance;
    }
}
```